# How to Fix TLS CBC Incorrect Padding Abuse Vulnerability on Windows 2003 Server

Tags: security, ssl

I am at a loss on this one, I have tried everything. We can not pass our PCI scan due to a couple of older Windows 2003 Servers with IIS.  The vulnerability reported is:

"TLS CBC Incorrect Padding Abuse Vulnerability"

This is the result from SSlLabs scanner:
[image: SSL Scan Results]

We have disabled SSL 3.0:
[image: Disabled SSL 3.0]

And installed the hotfixes from MS from here:

I don't know what else to do in order to disable the CBC chiper issues on Windows 2003. Does anybody know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue reported by SSL Labs is the [POODLE attack against TLS](https://community.qualys.com/blogs/securitylabs/2014/12/08/poodle-bites-tls). This is different from the SSL POODLE issue for which you appear to have deployed a fix.

Do you have a load balancer or reverse-proxy in front of your IIS server? If so, you'll need to patch that product.

If not, [there is a user report](https://community.qualys.com/message/28072#28072) [(also here)](http://forums.iis.net/post/2096123.aspx) that applying [KB2655992](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2655992) may address this.